# htaccess rewrite rule for multiple pages with same paramaeters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have been working on htaccess rewrite rule for below 2 urls:

`example.com/main-page.php?pagename=web-hosting` which changes to `example.com/basichosting/web-hosting`

`example.com/sub-page.php?pagename=vps-server` which changes to `example.com/advancedhosting/vps-server`

I use the following .htaccess rewrite rule and it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^basichosting/([A-Za-z0-9_'-]+)$ main-page.php?pagename=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^advancedhosting/([A-Za-z0-9_'-]+)$ sub-page.php?pagename=$1 [L]
```

What I actually want is my urls to look like

`example.com/hosting/web-hosting`

`example.com/hosting/vps-server`

Is it possible to change 'basichosting' and 'advancedhosting' to 'hosting' for the corresponding page name

Or else is it possible to hide 'basichosting' and 'advancedhosting' from the urls.

If so how can I write my htaccess rewrite rule?

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

##Rules for existing php files rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

##Rules for external rewrite to hosting uri as per OP need.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/main\.php\?pagename=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /hosting/%1? [R=301,L]
##Rules for internal rewrite to main.php file.
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$ main.php?pagename=$1 [L]

##Rules for external rewrite to hosting uri as per OP need.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/sub\.php\?pagename=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /hosting/%1? [R=301,L]
##Rules for internal rewrite to sub.php file.
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  sub.php?pagename=$1 [L]

<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 3000
   php_value memory_limit 64M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 3000
   php_value memory_limit 64M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

##Rules for internal rewrite to hosting uri as per OP need.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^hosting/(.*)/?$ main.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)/?$ sub.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]

##Rules for existing php files rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 3000
   php_value memory_limit 64M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 3000
   php_value memory_limit 64M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: These are just sample pagenames...I have many pages like this..                      
when hitting 'example.com/hosting/web-hosting' should goto 'example.com/main-page.php?pagename=web-hosting'                 

when hitting 'example.com/hosting/vps-server'  should goto 'example.com/sub-page.php?pagename=vps-server

Comment: This rule will work only for main.php not for sub.php..

If i write same rule for sub.php, only main.php works

Comment: @user_59910105, That's why I asked in previous comments, how htaccess will know which URL should go to main.php AND which should go to sub.php? You said you need regex I have written but regex can't be useful until its fully aware which link should go to which php file. So let me know Rules like: if a uri contains `bla` it should go to main.php OR if a uri contains `test it should go to sub.php like that, then I can write for you.

Comment: if a pagename contains 'hosting' it should go to main.php OR if a pagename contains 'server' it should go to sub.php

Comment: @user_59910105, ok that was cool information I was looking for. Rules are edited now, please do check once and let me know then.

Comment: This rule is similar to my question.. Still i got the clarity for answer i am looking for.. Thank u for your time..

Comment: @user_59910105, Your welcome, but actually speaking this rule is different from your 1st shown code, I am Happy I could help you on this one, cheers and keep posting nice Q & A cheers.